# I want to know how I could add a variable into innerHtml

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like

```
document.write("Your name is "+name+".");
```

but with innerHtml I tried

```
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "Your name is "+name+"."
```

and got an error

index.html:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined
    at index.html:10

my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="example"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var name = "Mixlanded"
var example = getElementById('example')
example.innerHTML = 'Your name is ' + name + '.'
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: Add a div with an id of example in your HTML document

Comment: do you have `<div id="example"></div>` anywhere on your page? `document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "Your name is "+name+"."` looks like it should work.

Comment: index.html:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined
    at index.html:10

Comment: It's `document.getElementById('example')` not just `getElementById('example')`

Comment: Instead of `getElementById('example')` should be `document.getElementById('example')` and the error is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code should work perfect

- But, just check that your JavaScript code is executed after the Html code `<div id="example"></div>` is available

Code:

```js
const name = 'Mixlanded'
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = 'Your name is ' + name + '.'
```

```html
<p id="example"></p>
```

Comment: This should be marked as duplicate and not answered.

Comment: The error could be that the JavaScript is executed before the Html is available.. Read my improved answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your comments.. @RacilHilan I am trying to delete but do not allow me as the answer has been accepted

Comment: Yes you cannot delete it after it is accepted. You can vote to close the question. Once the question is deleted, it takes all answers down with it.

Comment: @RacilHilan I have already voted to close as the issue for the answer has been clarified and fixed

Answer (score 0):

just used `document.getElementById('example')` and error gone

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="example"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var name = "Mixlanded"
var example = document.getElementById('example')
example.innerHTML = 'Your name is ' + name + '.'
</script>
</body>
</html>
```